# Check if x is in interval without looping

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, intervals

I'm having trouble avoiding loops in Matlab. I'm told loops cause poor performances so I'm reworking a code that's already working with loops.

I have a vector big vector x containing values, and a smaller X, also containing value. For each value x, I have to know in which interval i it is. I define the ith interval as the values between X_i-1 and X_i. For now, I'm doing this:

```
len = length(x);
is = zeros(len, 1); % Interval for each x
for j=1:len
    i=1; % Start interval
    while(x(j)<X(i-1) || x(j)>X(i)) % Please consider accessing X(0) won't crash it's a simplification to make the code clearer for you.
         i = i + 1;
    end
    is(j) = i;
end
```

What's the way to do it without those loops ?

EDIT: To help you understand the situation, here's a real example of what I'm trying to do here. With these inputs

```
X = [1 3 4 5]
x = [1 1.5 3.6 4.7 2.25]
```

I'd like `is` to be

```
% The 2 first and the 5th are in the first interval [1, 3]
% The 3rd is in [3, 4] and the 4th is in [4, 5]
is = [1 1 2 3 1]
```

Comment: You're told wrong, loops don't (unconditionally) cause poor performance.  Recent releases of Matlab have steadily improved the performance of loops (in general) in comparison with the performance of equivalent vectorised code.  Now that you've been told otherwise, do you still want to rework your code ?

Comment: Actually I'll be graded by the same guy who thinks loops aren't fine, so I kinda have to rework it, even if it's not really necessary...

Comment: So edit your question, someone might take sympathy on your situation.  But not me. It's not that I don't care, I really, really do, but it's beer o'clock here.

Comment: Haha, cheers mate!  @francoisr - High Performance Mark is not wrong.

Comment: Please give expected output.

Comment: I just added it. Does this help?

Answer (score 4):

Obvious homework, so I'll just point you to two functions that might help you:

- If your list of intervals has a constant spacing, have a look at `floor` and figure out how you can compute the index directly.
- If the intervals are irregularly spaced, have a lookt at `histc`, especially look at the form with 2 output arguments.

One more issue with your example code: try to understand what happens when `x(j)` is outside of any interval.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I looked into `histc`and I can't use it because my x vector is not sorted in increasing order, and I can't sort it. Maybe loops are the only option in this case ? I'm just looking for a cleverer way to do what I already do with the loop :/

Comment: Why can't you sort `x`?

Comment: If I sort it, it won't make any sense in the rest of the script. I could sort it, but i'll have to "unsort" after computing `is` for the rest of the script to work. :/

Comment: So just sort `x` and any other variables that `x` is linked to, right at the start of your script. Save the sort indices and then you can reapply them after the `histc` step. Preparing data properly for processing is an important part of writing any code.

Comment: I'm willing to do that, but will it improve my already working code? Because it's quite a big change to work on.

Comment: Tell your teacher that having intervals that are not sorted makes no sense at all. If `X = [1,3,2]` then 2.5 is both in the first and second interval.

Comment: Intervals are sorted, they're stored in `X` which is definitely sorted, but `x`isn't.

Comment: In [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), the `x` parameter does not need to be sorted, only the `binranges`, which is your `X`, so it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using masks, then I shift the second mask, and then I use `find` to return the index of ones:

```
ranges = [1,2,3,4]; %<br>
a = 1.5; %<br>
m1 = (a >= ranges); % will be [1, 0, 0, 0] <br>
m2 = (a <= ranges); % will be [0, 1, 1, 1] <br>
m2(1:end-1) = m2(2:end); % will be [1, 1, 1, 1], I am trying to shift this mask <br>
m2(end) = 0; % will be [1, 1, 1, 0], the mask shift is completed <br>
b = find( m1 & m2); % this will return 1 so your value is between 1 and 2 <br>
```